# mascara input javascript number with country

Tags: javascript, jquery-mask

I need to put a mask in the field with javascript. example:
+55 (11) 98888-0000 or +55 (11) 8888-0000.

I have a javascript function that works like this (11) 99999-9999 or (11) 9999-9999, I need to modify it to leave as above example.
Here is the function code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Mascara Telefone</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <html>
<head>
    <title>Mascara Telefone</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Máscaras ER */
function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}
function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
function mtel(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                  // Removes all non-digit
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); // Place parentheses around the first two digits
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    // Places hyphen between the fourth and fifth digits
    return v;
}
function id( el ){
 return document.getElementById( el );
}
window.onload = function(){
 id('telefone').onkeyup = function(){
  mascara( this, mtel );
 }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" maxlength="15" />

</body>
</html>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a condition based on length of your text of input to the function

> for +55 (11) 8888-0000 this use below  exp
>   v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d)/g,"+"+"$1 ($2) $3-$4"); and max-lenth=18
>
> for +55 (11) 98888-0000 use below exp
>   v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d)/g,"+"+"$1 ($2) $3-$4");and max-length=19

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Mascara Telefone</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <html>
<head>
    <title>Mascara Telefone</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Máscaras ER */
function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}
function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}
function mtel(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                  // Removes all non-digit
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d)/g,"+"+"$1 ($2) $3-$4");
    return v;
}
function id( el ){
 return document.getElementById( el );
}
window.onload = function(){
 id('telefone').onkeyup = function(){
  mascara( this, mtel );
 }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" maxlength="19" />

</body>
</html>
 </body>
</html>
```